# Why does my docker build fail on jenkins agent?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my `Jenkinsfile` pipeline in a project

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'docker:dind'
            args '-u root:root -p 3000:3000 --privileged'
        }
    }

    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }

    stages {
        stage('docker build') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'docker build --label v1.0.0 -t myrepo/myapp:v1.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a jenkins master and slave agent respectively. The above pipeline works well in master node, but if run in a slave agent node, then it would met the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am pretty sure that docker is running on the agent node because I can ssh to it and run docker commands successfully.

Why it behaves differently between running on master and slave agent? How should I fix it? Thanks very much!

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue ? Login as user that jenkins uses and see if you are able to run docker commands on slave agent ?

Comment: Notice the `args "-u root:root"` part, I have forced use the root user so it should not have permissions issue, right?

Comment: I was thinking that executes docker run command as root & it creates a container out of your image and runs docker daemon within your container as root user. Other users will be able to access it only using sudo or unless user is added to the docker group. I might be wrong here but that was my understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but I fixed it with the following change:  appened `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` to args.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'docker:dind'
            args '-u root:root -p 3000:3000 --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        }
    }

    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }

    stages {
        stage('docker build') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'docker build --label v1.0.0 -t myrepo/myapp:v1.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the line that you appended basically means that you have connected `docker daemon` of the host to the container. So, now you can run docker commands inside the container however, they will be using the docker daemon currently running on the host. I assume that you are using Jenkins inside docker container and there if you run build commands you need a connection to docker daemon. So either you can install docker in the container and run it using the `--privileged` option and start docker service inside the container or just give the container access to docker daemon running on the host.